# How can I write each line of this python print function to a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

I have...

```
>>> for i in range(11):
...     for j in range(103):
...             print "./", '%02d' % i, "/IMG", '%04d' % j, ".jpg"
...
>>> (prints a whole bunch of lines representing files in a group of directories)
```

...and what I want instead is to concatenate the little strings and ints in those lines into single strings, and append it to a list which will comprise approximately 1100 elements, each of which is the name of a file. How can I amend the loop?

Comment: mind if I ask why? just curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

ITYM

```
l = []
for i in range(11):
    for j in range(103):
        l.append()
```

or, shorter,

```
l = ['./%02d/IMG%04d.jpg' % (i, j) for i in range(11) for j in range(103)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
['./%02d/IMG%04d.jpg' % (i, j) for i in range(11) for j in xrange(103)]
```

Comment: why did you use `range` in the inner and `xrange` in the outer @Ignacio?

Comment: @BrainStorm: With small values, it can be faster to create the entire list up front instead of generating each value in turn.

Comment: I think the time taken by the string interpolation will swamp any micro optimization of range vs xrange

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import product
['./%02d/IMG%04d.jpg'%item for item in product(range(11),range(103))]
```

or slightly(~6%) faster but more obfuscated

```
 map('./%02d/IMG%04d.jpg'.__mod__, product(range(11),range(103)))
```

```
$ python -m timeit -s"from itertools import product" "['./%02d/IMG%04d.jpg'%item for item in product(range(11),range(103))]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s"from itertools import product" "map('./%02d/IMG%04d.jpg'.__mod__, product(range(11),range(103)))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 msec per loop
```

Comment: Any theories as to why `map` would produce faster code than the equivalent list comprehension? Don't they work in basically the same way internally?

Comment: @gnibbler Gnibbler, "Crawler of the Arcanes". +1 for ``__mod__``